# How to retrieve the WWNN of a host using pyvmomi?

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

I want to retrieve the WWNN number of a host using pyvmomi python library?
Tried using vim.host.HostBusAdapter but it doesnt provide the WWNN.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using vim.host.FibreChannelHba: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-6-5/topic/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.host.FibreChannelHba.html